# How do I test a local variable inside a controller with Rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

In my `Dashboard#Index`, I have this:

```
  def index        
    tagged_nodes = Node.includes(:user_tags).tagged_with(current_user.email)    
  end
```

How do I test this with RSpec?

I tried:

```
  expect(assigns(tagged_nodes)).to match Node.includes(:user_tags).tagged_with(u1.email)
```

But that gives me this error:

```
 NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `tagged_nodes' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::DashboardController::GETIndex:0x007fe4edd7f058>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot (and should not) test local variables. However, you can and should test *instance* variables, which are the ones that start with `@`. For that you use the `assigns` helper, passing it the name of the instance variable as a symbol. If we want the value of the instance variable `@tagged_nodes`, we call `assigns(:tagged_nodes)` (note the `:`).

So if your controller method looks like this:

```
def index        
  @tagged_nodes = Node.includes(:user_tags).tagged_with(current_user.email)    
end
```

...you would access `@tagged_nodes` with `assigns(:tagged_nodes)`:

```
expect(assigns(:tagged_nodes))
  .to match Node.includes(:user_tags).tagged_with(u1.email)
```

Comment: Yeh....I know how to test instance variables. So should I have no local variables in my controller?

Comment: You can have local variables, but you don't need to test them. You should test the controller's outward behavior: given a certain request, what response it gives (or what data it passes to the view). Local variables are private state and in general you don't test private state.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```
def index        
  tagged_nodes = Node.includes(:user_tags).tagged_with(current_user.email)    
end
```

you would access tagged_nodes with **controller.tagged_nodes**

```
expect(controller.tagged_nodes)
  .to match Node.includes(:user_tags).tagged_with(u1.email)
```